# Wrapping the mathjax-react expression

Tags: css, reactjs, mathjax

I want to wrap the mathjax-react expression to the next line instead of adding the scroll.
wordWrap:"break-word", is not working.

The expression:

```
  const example1 = String.raw`\text{A force } \overrightarrow{F} = (5\hat{i} + 3\hat{j} + 2\hat{k})N\text{ is applied over a particle which displaces it from its origin to the point }\\ \overrightarrow{R} = (2\hat{i} - \hat{j})m. \text{The work done on the particle in joules is:}`;
```

Using MathComponent from

```
  <p style={{display:"inline-block", whiteSpace:"nowrap", maxWidth:"100%", overflowX:"auto", textAlign:"initial"}}>
                  <MathComponent tex={example1} display={true} /></p>
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoGmV.png)

By adding wordWrap:"break-word" and removing overflowX and whiteSpace.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac4Bu.png)

By adding overflow:"hidden", and width:"100%"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6eMw.png)

Comment: Do you even want the horizontal scroll on the paragraph? I think you need to remove `overflowX:"auto"` entirely, then you need to add `wordWrap:"break-word"` and to remove the `whiteSpace:"nowrap"`

Comment: @AdamThomas I have removed the whiteSpace and overflowX, added wordWrap but it goes out of the <div>, you can see the output above

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Either way, overflow auto isnt the way to solve this -- so this is actually closer rather than further away. Try additionally adding "overflow: hidden" and "width: 100%" and get back to me.

Comment: @AdamThomas by adding overflow:"hidden" it does hide the overflow expression but does not shift to the new line, have a look above

Comment: Probably the library is applying nowrap to its own elements :(. You might try to override it, `<MathComponent tex={example1} display={true} style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}} />`

Comment: No luck :( , it's not even responsive

Comment: Seems the lib doesnt pass through style. However Ive just realised, that you really want the `display` prop as false. That makes it go inline-text, Which is what you want as then it ought to wrap like any other text. On the P tag you still need to ensure there is overflow hidden, and that you are not using nowrap at any point.

Comment: All the answers I found on SO all imply the use of the settings/configuration to set the linebreaks, but I wasn't able to get it working in a codesandbox either. It looks like you resolved this by *not* using React as commented here in this github [issue](https://github.com/CharlieMcVicker/mathjax-react/issues/37#issuecomment-1264515199), yes?

Comment: @DrewReese yes it works with just using the scripts.

Comment: Might be worth providing an answer here then explaining what/how you resolved the issue. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the mathjax scripts instead:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: { inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]], displayMath:[["$$", "$$"], ["\\[","\\]"]] }, showMathMenu: false, messageStyle: "none" }); </script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" ></script>
```

declarations:

```
let node = React.createRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      renderMath();
    })

    const renderMath = () => {
      window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", window.MathJax.Hub, node.current])
    };
```

and render the content in the `<p ref={node}>` tag.